# How to find circular objects in an image?

Tags: image-processing

How could I use morphological processing to find circular objects in an image? More specifically, I need to detect road signs.

I need to get the "80 speed limit" sign from this image:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you described what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: This [blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) might be useful.

Comment: Also [this one](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/how-to-extract-traffic-signs-from-a-photograph)

Comment: Because the road signs will rarely be seen head-on, you probably want to generalize the question to detecting *elliptical* objects--perhaps just ellipses with near-vertical major axes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The following method doesn't require parameters and discovers also oblique views.

```
obl[transit_Image] :=
  (SelectComponents[
      MorphologicalComponents[
       DeleteSmallComponents@ChanVeseBinarize[#, "TargetColor" -> Red],
       Method -> "ConvexHull"],
      {"Count", "SemiAxes"}, Abs[Times @@ #2 Pi - #1] < #1/100 &]) & @ transit;

GraphicsGrid[{#, obl@# // Colorize, ImageMultiply[#, Image@Unitize@obl@#]} & /@ 
  (Import /@ ("http://tinyurl.com/" <> # &/@ {"aw74tvc", "aycppg4", "9vnfrko", "bak4uzx"}))]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to detect non-reddish edged ellipses just remove the `"TargetColor" -> Red` option.

Comment: That's more like it...! Will it work with red birds on signs, though? :)

Comment: @cormullion Your raven is one of my examples :D

Comment: :) I meant that, if the bird was bright red (like a parrot) it might upset things. But your code is too clever to be fooled, I think!

Comment: @cormullion Now we only have to find a photograph of a bright red bird sitting on a transit signal  and test it :)

Comment: will an [amphibian](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-559937-toad-on-road-sign.php) do?

Comment: @cormullion Please keep [@rm-rf](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) out of this :D

Comment: This is excellent, nicely done. +1

Comment: This is a great answer--but doesn't it respond to a different question? How is it valid to equate "circular" with "reddish"?

Comment: @whuber Not sure. Is it now equating "elliptical" with "reddish" ? :)

Comment: Yes. If you could get rid of the requirement that signs be reddish, you would have a solution. (*E.g.*, in the US many signs are white, yellow, or green; red is not as common.)

Comment: without the "TargetColor" option, three of your examples didn't work on my machine...

Comment: @cormullion Guess what? I tried the other one because it was the one with blue colored circles! Trying to fix it :( Thanks!

Comment: @whuber My suggestion didn't work ... trying to fix

Comment: currently doesn't work for the first picture at all - I'm getting black/black as result for it.

Comment: @vaxquis probably a version problem. Works here as posted http://i.stack.imgur.com/TzkWh.png

Comment: I do not get this part : `Abs[Times @@ #2 Pi - #1] < #1/100 &`. What does it calculate? Does subtract the area calculated by that of a circle and subtract it from the count?

Answer (score 27):

### Circular Hough Transform

I have had fun implementing a circular Hough transform based solution for this question (in part using some MMA9 `Image3D` functionality which has become available in between). By this shape-related approach we can overcome the color restrictions of the approaches tried so far.

The method starts with an edge detection, followed by a [circular Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_detection_process) (also see [this Java applet demonstration](http://www.markschulze.net/java/hough/), or [these lecture slides](http://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf), or [this paper](http://www.cvmt.dk/education/teaching/e07/MED3/IP/Simon_Pedersen_CircularHoughTransform.pdf)).

In the following this is demonstrated using a test picture (with inscribed radius numbers) taken from [www.markschulze.net/java/hough/](http://www.markschulze.net/java/hough/). For this implementation the core part is the extensive use of `ListConvolve`, while the convolution is being done using annulus-shaped kernels.

```
markschulze = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoqbW.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
markschulzeedges=EdgeDetect[markschulze, 10, Method -> "Sobel"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParallelMap[Image@
 Divide[
  ListConvolve[
   #, 
   ImageData@markschulzeedges, 
   Ceiling[(Length@#)/2]
  ],
  Total[#, 2]
 ] &, 
 Map[
  Function[{r}, DiskMatrix[r] - ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[r - 1], 1]][#] &, 
  Range[14, 18, 1]
 ]
]
```

{[image: Mathematica graphics],
[image: Mathematica graphics],
[image: Mathematica graphics],
[image: Mathematica graphics],
[image: Mathematica graphics]
}

These five images represent the circular Hough transform within the radius interval [14,18].

In order to utilize the transform for circle or circular area detection this transform is both binarized and labeled. According to the detected coordinates of candidate circles inside the 3D Hough transform volume, radii and image positions are determined, so that masks for the original image can be computed:

```
HoughCircleDetection[image_Image, radiusmin_Integer: 1, 
   radiusmax_Integer: 40, edgedetectradius_Integer: 10, 
   minfitvalue_Real: .25, radiusstep_Integer: 1, 
   minhoughvoxels_Integer: 4] := 
  Module[{edgeimage, hough3dbin, hough3dbinlabels, coords, arraydim},

   edgeimage = 
    SelectComponents[
     DeleteBorderComponents[
      EdgeDetect[image, edgedetectradius, Method -> "Sobel"]
     ],
     "EnclosingComponentCount", # == 0 &
    ];

   hough3dbin = 
    DeleteSmallComponents[
     Image3D[
      ParallelMap[
       Binarize[Image@
        Divide[
         ListConvolve[#, ImageData@edgeimage, Ceiling[(Length@#)/2]], 
         Total[#, 2]
        ],
        minfitvalue
       ] &,
       Map[
        Function[{r}, DiskMatrix[r] - ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[r - 1], 1]][#] &, 
        Range[radiusmin, radiusmax, radiusstep]
       ]
      ]
     ],
     minhoughvoxels
    ];

   hough3dbinlabels = MorphologicalComponents[hough3dbin];

   coords = 
    ParallelMap[
     Round[Mean[Position[hough3dbinlabels, #]]] &, 
     Sort[Rest@Tally@Flatten@hough3dbinlabels, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[All, 1]]
    ];

   arraydim = Rest@Dimensions[hough3dbinlabels];

   Print["Radii: ", radiusmin + coords[[All, 1]] - 1];

   ParallelMap[
    Function[{level, offx, offy},
     ImageMultiply[
      image,
      Image@ArrayPad[
       DiskMatrix[radiusmin + level - 1],
       {{offx - radiusmin - level, First@arraydim - offx - radiusmin - level + 1},
        {offy - radiusmin - level, Last@arraydim - offy - radiusmin - level + 1}}
      ]
     ]
    ][Sequence @@ #] &,
    coords
   ]

  ];
```

Practically it is useful to restrict the method to eligible radii. Also, sometimes parameters, like the edge detection radius, and the minimum fit value might be adapted:

```
Show[ImageApply[Plus, HoughCircleDetection[#, 14, 18, 10, .3]], 
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[#]] &[markschulze]
```

> Radii: {16,15,17,14,14}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The method appears to work quite specifically, though 13 is included here.

Let us see the results for the four images already used above:

```
Show[ImageApply[Plus, HoughCircleDetection[Import["http://tinyurl.com/aw74tvc"], 30, 50]],
     ImageSize -> 200
]
```

> Radii: {39,33}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here we find two more or less concentric hits.

```
Show[ImageApply[Plus, HoughCircleDetection[Import["http://tinyurl.com/aycppg4"], 20, 30, 
   15]],
    ImageSize -> 200
]
```

> Radii: {22}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Oblique views are a matter of luck, of course.

```
Show[ImageApply[Plus, HoughCircleDetection[Import["http://tinyurl.com/9vnfrko"], 20, 40]],
     ImageSize -> 200
]
```

> Radii: {24,24,24,23,24,24,22,24,24,22,22,24,23,24,22,22,24}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the No-U-turn sign is missed, the stop sign is included...

```
Show[ImageApply[Plus, HoughCircleDetection[Import["http://tinyurl.com/bak4uzx"], 20, 60]],
     ImageSize -> 200
]
```

> Radii: {54,38}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the No-parking sign again the inner and outer circle is found.

**For real life applications like road sign detection, for reasons of robustness feature combination is always being recommended.**

Comment: Very nice. Perhaps a link to a good explanation of the Circular Hough Transform may help future readers

Comment: Thanks, have added some references, and also have added some more or less didactic example. Sorry for a wrong `Floor` call inside `ListConvolve` for kernel alignmend, this was replaced by a `Ceiling` now, so all resulting images were replaced as well (I noticed a strange shift, this is now gone).

Comment: This is realy great, but I fail at getting the coordinates of the circles: eg. if I take coords[[All,{2,3}]] and place them with points on the image, they don't align with the circles I then obtain with ParallelMap that follows... Probably this is just me being dumb, sorry, but some help?

Comment: @mgm Run this, I guess you will notice how differently coordinates may need to be handled: `Module[{image, coords = {{2, 2}, {10, 20}, {20, 30}, {30, 40}}, 
  corrcoords, data},
 image = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
 corrcoords = 
  Map[{#[[1]], ImageDimensions[image][[2]] + 1 - #[[2]]} &, 
   Reverse[coords, 2]];
 Map[(image = 
     ImageCompose[image, 
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, 0}]}], # - {1, 0}]) &,
   corrcoords];
 data = ImageData[image];
 Map[(data[[#[[1]] - 1 ;; #[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] - 1 ;; #[[2]] + 1]] = 
     Table[{0, 0, 1}, {3}, {3}]) &, coords]; Image@data
 ]`

Answer (score 20):

Basically, you import the image:

```
i = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Crow_on_the_sign_of_no_parking.jpg"]
```

[image: image from wikimedia]

Tidy it up:

```
mb = MorphologicalBinarize[i]
```

[image: mbinarize]

Isolate the areas of interest:

```
cn = ColorNegate[Closing [mb, 10]]
```

[image: color negate]

Use component analysis:

```
sc = SelectComponents[
  cn, {"Eccentricity", 
   "Circularity"}, #1 < .5  && #2 < 0.8 &];
Colorize[sc]
```

[image: select components]

Now use this information to process your original image...

```
ImageApply[# * 0.25 &, i, Masking -> ColorNegate[sc]]
```

[image: apply]

Of course, I've cheated in this answer: to process arbitrary images - or to detect crows on road signs - is much much harder!

(I chose this image because, when I wrote this answer, you hadn't supplied your example.)

Comment: This is good! Try to do this also for image in my question. 

Is there are is way to use EdgeDetect?

Comment: Have a go, show us what happens ... :)

Comment: How now get using this information (Colorized) to select sign from original image?

Comment: have a look at some of the relevant tutorials and videos: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html should be built-in to the help; http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=97&video=839 is a good video introduction

Comment: See https://goo.gl/M5xuRQ