# CirclePoints and CircleThrough

Tags: fitting, geometry

```
$Version
```

> 12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)

---

For points (located on a unit circle),

```
pts = CirclePoints[11]
```

$$\left\{\left\{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right),-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)\right\}, ...\right.$$

```
Graphics[{
  Blue, Circle[],
  Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@pts
  }]
```

[image]

[image]

**Question(s)**

- Is this version related or is there a limit on how many points the `CircleThrough` algorithm can fit?
- For fitting random points to the best-fit circle, I have already looked at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65670/fitting-data-to-a-circle-with-findfit) post. I wonder if any built-in function has been provided since?

*Note(1)* For 10 points it works with `pts//N`. For 11 pts, it doesn't work with either variation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like a bug. 8 points worked, but nothing above 8.    `pts = CirclePoints[8]
Graphics[{Line[pts], Point[pts], {Red, CircleThrough[pts]}}]`  V 12.3.1

Comment: Everyone who is helping out, please include version info. Thanks. @Nasser

Comment: v12.2 works for `<= 10 points`

Comment: V12.3.0 `Graphics[CircleThrough[pts[[1 ;; 4]]]]`does not work

Comment: Three points define a circle. Use `CircleThrough[RandomChoice[CirclePoints[20], 3]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thanks. I thought so too that there was an upper limit. The documentation, as well as the behavior, lead one to think that more points can be accomodated.