# How to Invert MorphologicalComponents?

Tags: image-processing

It's actually the same question as here: [Identify circles in Image and make list of all diameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145631/identify-circles-in-image-and-make-list-of-all-diameters)

...but I cannot get it to work properly for this specific case, so I would be pleased for some help. I don't see where the error is.

[image]

What you see is photoresist pillars on a glass substrate. 
What I would like to do, is to get the mean diameter in x and y-direction as well as the mean period in x- and y-direction.

Now, instead of doing all the measurement manually, I was wondering, if maybe there is a way to automate it using mathematica ?

So, I wrote this code:

```
img = Import["image_01.jpg"];
binarized = MorphologicalBinarize[img, {0.3, 0.7}];
cutImage = ImageTake[binarized, {10, 680}, {0, 850}]
```

[image]

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[cutImage] //Colorize
```

[image]

As you can see thanks to the `//Colorize`, `MorphologicalComponents` sees the substrate as a component, but I would like to have the ellipses as components to measure them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[cutImage];
params = ComponentMeasurements[Image[1 - components], 
   {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}] // Values;
HighlightImage[cutImage, 
 Graphics[{Red, {Point[#[[1]]], Rotate[Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[3]]]} & /@ params}]]
```

[image]

```
params2 = ComponentMeasurements[DeleteSmallComponents@Image[1 - components], 
   {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}] // Values;
HighlightImage[cutImage, 
 Graphics[{Red, {Point[#[[1]]], Rotate[Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[3]]]} & /@ params2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that you could do [1 - components] since 1 is an integer and components a matrix. But it seems to be working fine ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @james, you are most welcome.

Comment: Mathamtica is so streight-forward. Hmm, how am I going to delete all the small components in my image ? Ah, yes, 'DeleteSmallComponents' will do the trick. Nice!

Comment: You don't need `MorphologicalComponents` here, `ComponentMeasurements[1 - cutImage` will do the same thing

Comment: Thank you, @NikiEstner. Great point.