# How to locate a text string in a picture?

Tags: image-processing, text

We can use TextRecognize to recognize lines of text and their corresponding bounding boxes. For the text in the picture below, how can we detect the bounding boxs of the text in the picture.

[image]

The picture may be rotated. For this kind of pictures, select the color of the background of the text may not be useful. Because the background may also contain this color(There may be some pink clouds in the sky). I think we can try to find the zigzag lines in a picture and in most cases theses lines are "text".

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/how-to-find-circular-objects-in-an-image)? It's not about text in a bounding box as such, but I would guess that an answer to your question could build on what's suggested there.